# Return value in last quotation in php

Tags: php, regex

How would I go about returning the last value inside quotes of the string below using PHP. In this case the value is 200, but this is dynamic?

```
 {"amount_id_341":"200"}
```

Comment: Are you looking to parse a JSON string?

Comment: I see that is JSON, but I will not know the id value, so I'll need to parse the entire string without knowing the id value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = '{"amount_id_341":"200"}';

echo end(json_decode($str, true));
```

Comment: Looks like the easy way to do this. Unfortunately Just found out that this needs to be done within smarty template

Comment: It's possible, just insert the smarty php tags to include custom php code into the template. OT : Smarty isn't even close to a template engine like Mustache, which would make things a lot easier in your case (just an opinion about the subject).

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is also [JSON](http://www.json.org/) so you could convert it to a PHP array and get the value that way:

```
$json = json_decode('{"amount_id_341":"200"}', true);
echo $json['amount_id_341'];
```

[The boolean is to convert it into an associative array instead of an object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), which I find easier to work with in PHP.

In case you don't know the property's name, you can use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
$json = json_decode('{"amount_id_341":"200"}', true);
$vals = array_values($json);
echo $vals[0];
```

Or [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) like Patrick mentionned in the comments:

```
$json = json_decode('{"amount_id_341":"200"}', true);
echo array_pop($json);
```

Comment: Did not know it was Json, I won't know the amount id beforehand, so this may not work.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the OP may be referring to php's habit of treating like number most of the things that *look* like number. E.g. `var_dump( '0' == '0x0' );` yelds `bool(true)`. In this particular case you can, of course, use `===`, but generally I don't know of a better way to deal with the problem than quitting php altogether.

Comment: Use array_pop to get the last element on an array instead of array_values

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with `explode`:

```
$str = '{"amount_id_341":"200"}';
$parts = explode('"', $str);

echo $parts[3];
```

Else here's a regex that would get you the information:

```
$str = '{"amount_id_341":"200"}';
$pattern = '/([^"]*)"\}$/';
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);

echo end($matches);
```

And there's also the possibility to use `json_decode`:

```
$str = '{"amount_id_341":"200"}';
echo end(json_decode($str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex solution:

```
preg_match('/^.*:"(.*)"/', '{"amount_id_341":"200"}', $res);
print $res[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

### Parsing quoted substrings

To get the contents of the *last* double quoted substring, implies that you need to parse *all* double quoted substrings. And if your context includes single quoted strings, you'll need to parse all of those too, because a single quoted string may contain double quotes (and vice-verse). Adding the additional requirement that a quoted string may contain escaped characters (including escaped quotes), results in a non-trivial regex solution. And to do this robustly, we must also first validate that the string consists of only properly opened-and-closed quoted sub-strings intermixed with non-quoted material.

We can achieve all objectives at once with the following PHP function which returns the contents of the last double quoted substring, if any:

```php
// Return contents of last double quoted substring, if any.
function getLastDoubleQuotedSubstring($text) {
    $re_valid_quotes = '/ # Rev:20111031
        # Validate string of quoted and non-quoted substrings.
        ^                 # Anchor to start of string.
        (?:               # Group of 3 global alternatives.
          ([^"\']+)       # Either $1: One or more non-quotes.
          (?=[\'"]|$)     # Anchor end to next alternative.
        | (")             # Or $2: a double quoted string.
          (               # $3: Double-quoted contents.
            [^"\\\\]*     # {normal*} Zero or more non-", non-\.
            (?:           # Begin "Unrolling-the-loop". C-MRE3.
              \\\\[\S\s]  # {special} Escape anything.
              [^"\\\\]*   # {normal*} Zero or more non-", non-\.
            )*            # {(special normal*)*}
          )               # End $3: Double-quoted contents.
          "               # Closing quote.
        | (\')            # Or $4: a single quoted string.
          (               # $5: Single-quoted contents.
            [^\'\\\\]*    # {normal*} Zero or more non-\', non-\.
            (?:           # Begin "Unrolling-the-loop". C-MRE3.
              \\\\[\S\s]  # {special} Escape anything.
              [^\'\\\\]*  # {normal*} Zero or more non-\', non-\.
            )*            # {(special normal*)*}
          )               # End $5: Single-quoted contents.
          \'              # Closing quote.
        )*                # Zero or more global alternatives.
        $                 # Anchor to end of string.
        /x';
    if (preg_match($re_valid_quotes, $text, $matches) && isset($matches[3]))
        return $matches[3];
    return  FALSE; // else there was no valid last double quoted substring.
}
```

### Example Input:

Here are some valid example strings with increasing complexity:

`out1 "d1" out2`
`out1 "d1" out2 "d2" out3`
`out1 "d1" out2 's1' out3 "d2" out4 's2' out5`
`out1 "d1'd1" out2 's1"s1' out3 "d2'd2" out4`
`out1 "d1\"d1" out2 's1\'s1' out3 "d2\"d2" out4`

### Example Output:

`d1`
`d2`
`d2`
`d2'd2`
`d2\"d2`

### Invalid Input:

Here are some examples of invalid strings (result should be `FALSE`):

`out1 "d1 out2`
`out1 "d1 out2 "d2" out3`
`out1 "d1 's1" ' out2`